# Unstable Simulation At Low max_step_size?

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My entire world:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<sdf version="1.5">
    <world name="bin-picking">
        <physics type="ode">
            <max_step_size>0.050</max_step_size>
            <real_time_update_rate>0</real_time_update_rate>
        </physics>
        <include><uri>model://ground_plane</uri></include>
        <include><uri>model://sun</uri></include>
        <include><uri>model://triangle</uri><name>triangle_0</name><pose> 1.5  -0.705 1.075   0   0       1.134</pose></include>
    </world>
</sdf>
```

Here is the triangle model:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.5'>
  <model name='cylinder'>
    <link name='link'>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
              <radius>.5</radius>
              <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
              <radius>.5</radius>
              <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Running this: `gazebo --verbose my_world.world` will produce an unstable simulation with jittery ground plane collision that never ends in Gazebo 6.5.1, like in [this video](https://github.com/xanderdunn/storage/blob/master/triangle_unstable.mov).

This appears to be entirely a result of having a large `max_step_size`.  A value of 0.001, for example, will not cause this problem.  The environment will appear stable.  Is this instability at large step sizes expected?  What explains it?

Our difficulty with using small step sizes is that it affects the camera's rendering rate and we'd like to have the camera rendering at a certain rate in relation to physics updates.

Modifying my .world file to use the "world" solver helped the stability of it:

```
<world name="bin-picking">
    <physics type="ode">
        <max_step_size>0.050</max_step_size>
        <real_time_update_rate>20</real_time_update_rate>
        <ode>
            <solver>
                <type>world</type>
            </solver>
        </ode>
    </physics>
```

The above situation with a single triangle is now stable.  However, slightly more complicated scenes, like a scene with 2 boxes, 2 cylinders, 2 triangles, and 2 hexagons will exhibit some of this collision instability simply from running the simulation without any interaction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12913/unstable-simulation-at-low-max_step_size?/) by [xanderai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2517/xanderai/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Simulation will become increasingly more unstable the larger the step size. This is just how a fixed time step size physics simulation operates.

Your model however lacks `<inertia>` which will cause your model to be unstable. You should definitely fix that.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xanderai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2517/xanderai/) on 2016-03-28**:
Thanks.  In my complete .world, all of the objects have proper inertia.  I just removed it for the minimal reproducible example above.  We can simply take multiple time steps at a smaller step size for the same effect.

**Comment by [xanderai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2517/xanderai/) on 2016-03-30**:
We were able to solve our instability while maintaining the `max_step_size` that's convenient for us by switching from the ODE (explicit) physics engine to the Simbody (implicit) physics engine.  More here: https://vimeo.com/107517366

**Comment by [JakobThumm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46581/jakobthumm/) on 2021-06-22**:
Unfortunately, the vimeo link is down.
Can you describe how switching to simbody fixed the issue?
What solver parameters did you use?